# Cant see product images in backend after upgrading to 1.9.0.3

Tags: magento-1.9

I have recently upgraded my magento site to 1.9.0.3 but now I cant see product images in the backend, please help???

Thanks

Andy

Comment: add below code in php.ini file on root

memory_limit = 512M
in admin panel go to admin->system->cache management and click Flush Catalog Images Cache

Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the /media directory is in your Apache web server's group (usually 'www-data' or 'httpd'). Magento also needs to be able to write to this directory, so you can run this command to set those permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/magento/media
```

Comment: Hi, I have made sure the media folder has full access but it is still the same???

Comment: frontend images showing ??

Comment: Yes visible in the front end but not in the backend on all products added before I upgraded.